# Permission to Start Activity denied

Tags: c#, selenium, appium

I'm trying to run my test via Appium's server but getting the error:

```
Permission to start activity denied
```

I'm actually trying to run Chrome app(without providing the APK. the app is already installed on my phone).

```
appPackage: "com.android.chrome"
appActivity : "org.chromium.chrome.browser.ChromeTabbedActivity"
```

However, when I'm running the same test with Appium's client GUI, everything works great.
Still, I would like to use the server(running Appium with CMD) and not by GUI.

Comment: seems like I found a workaround. 
I have added the capability : 
 capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "Chrome");
so why do I need the appPackage and appActivity in that case?

Comment: are you sure appPackage and appActivity are correct

Comment: As I said,it works great when using these capabilities when running appium's GUI so I can only guess they are correct. I used a shell command to verify it and it looked correct.

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
appPackage: "com.android.chrome"
appActivity : "com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main"
```

In my case it is working.Hope these help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are launching activity which has android exported= True To solve this issue follow below steps Set path for SDK/build-tools Now from command prompt run aapt dumb badging "path of apk" find Launchable activity This will work